# R GRNN model is taking too long to predict

Tags: r

I want to apply a General regression neural network model in R using the GRNN package. I don't know what the problem is, but it takes too long to run this code. It's taking forever for the loop to complete.

My system has 4 GB RAM and has an i5 first gen processor (I know it's old but that's all I have right now). Is it because of my system configuration or something wrong with the code?

Training data has 3673 observations of 12 variables and testing has 1225 observations of 12 variables. All variables are numeric

```
nn <- learn(training, variable.column=length)
nn <- smooth(nn, sigma = 0.9)


for(i in 1:nrow(testing))
{   
  vec <- as.matrix(testing[i,])
  res <- guess(nn, vec)

  if(is.nan(res))
  {
    cat("Entry ",i," Generated NaN result!\n")
  }
  else
  {
    result$predict[i] <- res
  }
  i = i+1
}
```